# Installing Pillow for Python 3.6 on Windows

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am new for Python and Django, I am trying about Pillow but When I install Pillow via pip install Pillow from Python Command Shell, I get the message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa6 in position 79: invalid start byte
```

And I google and try but all failed. Can any one help ?

Comment: You can try to change the active console Code Page. Simply run `CHCP 437` before `pip install ...`.

Comment: I had tried to execute this command and then pip install Pillow via openning python command shell, same as before.

Answer (score 0):

For third-party modules for Windows, I recommend  Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). The latest version of Pillow is [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)

Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: I had downloaded and installed but it failed as previous example. According to the error message, is it possible the reason comes from ole module, because the message start from the ole module, both the oficial and non-oficial .whl are same.

Comment: I use the VS2017 Professional Preview as development tool, and create the virtualenv via VS2017, and I install only one version of Python but with x64 edition for Windows 10 and Python and Christoph's extension packages I downloaded is amd64 too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to download the Python package from [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It has a lot of packages already installed for you, and is hassle free to download and install.